# Code completion shortcut key settings for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to set the tab key to code completion confirmation and code completion selection in vscode

I try to write code in vscode and use the tab key to confirm and select code completion.And I finally hope to make the tab key have the effect of code selection and code confirmation at the same time. How can I set it to get this effect?

Comment: have you tried looking at the keyboard shortcuts? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings <-- docs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.